# Integrating Selenium with HP ALM

Tags: java, selenium, ant, hp-quality-center

We have a requirement to understand if Selenium could be integrated with HP ALM. The requirement is to execute the Selenium scripts from ALM and to update back the results in ALM. From the research done till now we have got to know that it is possible by using VAPI-XP script, XTools.Run and Ant.

We are looking for a solution for integrating Selenium with HP ALM using any Java Framework like JUnit or TestNG.

If anyone has any source of information regarding this, please let us know.

We have got one similar discussion at [how to integrate selenium with QC?Please help](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/how-integrate-selenium-QC-Please-961927.S.57493355)

But the problem is when we follow the procedure told in the discussion we always get Pass result. We would like to update the status in HP ALM based on the exceptions and errors occurred during the execution of Selenium scripts. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, Did you found out any solutions for ALM integration.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [Agiletestware Bumblebee](http://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee.html).
It allows you to integrate HP ALM with Selenium and many more tools.
It also has Java annotations package to integrate your JUnit/TestNG tests with HP ALM by just adding some annotations to your Java code.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of Agiletestware Bumblebee

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:1** Please look in to below website. It has got all the stuffs related to updating test results to ALM Testset http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/2013/12/IntegrationWithQCorALMusingALMServiceWrapperPart2.html

**Solution:2**

1. Register HP ALM Client via ALM>>Help>>Addins page.
2. Download Jacob dll(Both 64,32 bit), jacob jar
3. Add it to your project path.(DLL--> Just copypaste to project path), Jacob.jar-->Add it to build path.
4. Create a class
5. Below example code gives you some idea about how to use COM API in java+Jacob

   ```
   QCConnection = new ActiveXComponent("TDApiOle80.TDConnection");
   Dispatch.call(QCConnection, "InitConnectionEx", sURL);
   // Login -User and Password
   Dispatch.call(QCConnection, "Login", sUser, sPassword);
   int iProjectsCount = Integer.parseInt(Dispatch.call(oProjects, "Count").toString());
   ```

**Below is the JACOB equivalent COM code**

```
Set QCConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")

QCConnection.InitConnectionEx  sQCUrl   

QCConnection.Login sUserName, sPassword
```